# Alterar o parâmetro de uma rota

Tags: ionic3, aba

Tenho uma aplicação **ionic** em que eu uso **tabs** com duas paginas diferentes e tenho que passar parâmetros para elas.

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs color="credisis" *ngIf="pagador">
    <ion-tab tabIcon="person" tabTitle="Pagador eletrônico" [root]="pagador ? tab1Root : tabTestRoot" [rootParams]="[pagador, dda]"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="people" tabTitle="Agregados" [root]="pagador ? tab2Root : tabTesteRoot" [rootParams]="pagador ? pagador.agregados : ''"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

O usuário pode clicar em um botão e atualizar esses dados. Porém os dados só atualizam na página que contém as **tabs**, e não nas páginas que as **tabs** chamam. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Você quer que ao clicar em um botão seja redirecionado e passado parâmetros para outra página?

Comment: Na verdade, eu só queria enviar os parâmetros novamente, para atualizar os dados na página

Comment: Mas, para mim não está claro quando e como você quer enviar os parâmetros? você quer enviar ao clicar no menu tab? ou quando clicar em algum botão?

Comment: Vou tentar simplificar, ao entrar em uma pagina que contém duas `tabs`, eu faço uma consulta de `pagador`. Eu já passo esses dados como parâmetros com o `rootparams`, porém um certo botão atualiza esse dado, porém o parâmetro não atualiza junto